# Woocommerce - Show total items on order details, need to find out where to position it

Tags: php, filter, addition

I found the answer to this question, but I do not know on what position to include the code.

including code in woocommerce/templates/order/order-details.php.

```
    add_filter('woocommerce_order_items_table', 'add_items_count_on_order_page');
    function add_items_count_on_order_page($order){    ?>
    <tr class="cart-subtotal">
    <th><?php _e( 'Product Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
    <td><?php echo $order->get_item_count();?></td>
    </tr>    <?php
}
```

I try to include this piece of code in woocommerce/templates/order/order-details.php
I tried it on different lines.
I have no result.

Answer (score 0):

The code which you have is the `filter`, you can add this piece of code into your current theme or child theme's `functions.php` file. And it should work.

There are 2 ways to this.

1. Extend woocommerce `order-details.php` template file in the child theme by copy/pasting the file in your `/child-theme/woocommerce/order/order-details.php` file and then modifying the filter there.

OR

2. just paste this piece of code in your child theme's `functions.php` file.

Comment: I did paste the piece of code in the functions.php file in my child theme.
Nothing appears in the new order emails, or de customer order-on-hold email. Can you help?

Comment: It seems that this `woocommerce_order_items_table` hook (filter) is deprecated. which version of woocommerce are you using?

Comment: See, your question is quite unclear. you should read [How to Ask Guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As I understood your question, you wish to show total items in the cart on the Order details page. There is a filter you can find `woocommerce_order_item_quantity_html` which is available on line #44 in `templates/order/order-details-item.php` file.